# comparing the url from the tabs to those in an array, and adding more to the array

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension

Hello so I am relatively new to using the chrome and javascript together,and I would like to request some help on how to proceed with the project I want to do. I want to create an extension and one of the main thing is to have a list (possibly an array) of urls. If the url of any of the tabs match the urls on the list then it closes. I was thinking of creating a for loop to cycle through the array of urls that were imputed like this

```
*://facebook.com/*
```

so that it matches all the possible urls. Based on this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

I started with this to show more or less the idea.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab.url){
if (tab.url===*://facebook.com/*){
chrome.tabs.remove(tab)
}
};
```

Another user helped me and corrected it to this if I only want to have 1 url, however due to the nature of what I want I am afraid that, that will not work. Perhaps if it was modified to include a for loop to see if they match the list of urls and if they do then close the tab or tabs.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
if (tab.url.indexOf('facebook.com') != -1) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
}
});
```

My second doubt is how to add and remove Urls to the array in case the user wants to do so. Since this is an extension I was thinking of making an HTML file appear on the click of a button (perhaps the option page) so that the user imputs the urls that should be on the url list there. However I am not sure on how to get the urls from there to the array or to whatever thing is going to be used.

Thanks in advance and I apologize for mistakes as English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to this one:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
for (var i = 0, len = urlArray.length; i < len; i++) {
if (tab.url.indexOf(urlArray[i]) > -1) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
}
});
```

For your second concern, if you just want to get input urls from html files to the array in JS. You may find more useful tutorial on the link:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_url.asp

Comment: Could you explain why have the >-1, I dont really understand why and I have seen people use it.

Comment: couldnt you just use i<urlArray.length instead of i<len and defining len before?

Comment: Also would the syntax of the array be ok like this var urlList =      ["*://facebook.com/*", "*://example.com/*", "*://google.com/*" ]; or without the " " or perhaps in another way? There are supposed to be written with the * (asterics) (like on the example in the op).

Comment: so would this work? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/831e0aa7e77d2a20455e or do I have to change something to make it work with this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

Comment: Well the >-1 is the same with !=-1. You can do that like i<urlArray.length instead. This is the usual way to create new array with urls: urlArray = [a, b, c]; Your code looks good to me.